# Move fontawesome to own bundle using dynamic import

Tags: reactjs, bundle, webpack-4, font-awesome-5

I am trying to reduce my bundle size by splitting it into several chunks. 
BundleAnalyzerPlugin tells me that Fontawesome is imported in full even though I have tried to only import the icons I need which seems odd.

[image: Fontawesome]

My fontawesome imports

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { faBell, faEyeSlash, faEye} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faBell as regularBell} from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';

...
library.add( faBell, faEye, faEyeSlash, regularBell, regularCalendarAlt)
```

My fontawesome version

```
"@fortawesome/fontawesome": "^1.1.5",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular": "^5.0.10",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid": "^5.0.10",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.8",
"@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.3",
```

I am trying to use the import() splitting technique [described here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) but can't figure out how to make it work for Fontawesome.

```
return import(/* webpackChunkName: "lodash" */ 'lodash').then(({ default: _ }) => {
  ...
}
```

How can I put split fontawesome into it's own bundle and load it synchronously?

Something along the lines of [Prefetching/Preloading](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) would work too, but those techniques seems to have very poor browser support? I sadly **need** support for Safari.

My webpack config

```
  // Set up webpack plugins
  config.plugins = [
    nodeEnvPlugin,
    firebasePlugin,
    cssExtractPlugin,
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(
      {
        excludeAssets: /node_modules/,
        statsOptions: {
          exclude: /node_modules/
        }
      }
    )
  ]
```

[image: BundleAnalyser result]

Kind regards /K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to view `node_modules` which shouldn't be part of your bundle upon deployment. You should be configuring your BundleAnalyzerPlugin to view the destination of webpack output instead. That way you could fully identify which are consuming big in terms of size.

Here's the option about it from your library of choice:

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer#bundledir

Here is mine implementing the same technique you have above on fontawesome optimization

[image]

Here's my repo for your reference: https://github.com/crrmacarse/crrmacarse.github.io

Comment: Ah, thanks! :D I am using BundleAnalyzerPlugin() as a webpack plugin and cannot seem to make it ignore node_modules. I have tried two approaches - "statsOptions" and "excludeAssets". See updated question. Many thanks! /K

Comment: Have you tried the CLI instead of adding it to plugin? You could start from here: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer#usage-as-a-cli-utility

Comment: You seem to not get my point. You shouldn't be scanning the whole projects but rather the "bundle" which webpack outputs. You could only see from there the optimizations you've done. It'll be either dist/ or public/ folder

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replying! I understand that I should NOT look at node_modules. :) However I cannot get the plugin to JUST look at "/dist". I will try the CLI, but Windows is flaky at handling CLIs :) I would prefer using the plugin! /K

Comment: I've just actually implemented it in my repo. Here's the commit so you'll have idea on how I did it: https://github.com/crrmacarse/crrmacarse.github.io/commit/fad5928a58c626b9b150df883fe18c1c1f8d8476

Comment: Thanks! Thats better! But... node_modules are *still* included in the stats. (?) Webpack is told to exclude node_modules. config.module = {rules: [{test:/\.(js|jsx)$/, exclude: [/node_modules/,/tests/] ... /K